# how to load root CA cert into azure

Tags: azure, certificate

I have the cert uploaded but I cant work out how to persuade azure to put it in the right place. I tried

- local machine CA -> cert goes to intermediate cas
- local machine Trust -> cert goes to Enterprise Trust

EDIT: I ended up writing a little exe that gets run by a startup task

Comment: Care to share the source code to add the cert?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is LocalMachine -> Root, but Azure doesn't support putting certificates in the local machine root.  The closest you can achieve is using CurrentUser -> Root.

Comment: but that doesnt put the cert anywhere useful. Looks like I will have to write custom startup code

Comment: I'd try this link then, it didn't work for me, but that may have been because of my certificate: http://www.leastprivilege.com/AddingACertificateToTheRootCertificateStoreFromTheCommandLineEgAsAnAzureStartupTask.aspx